# Producing gradients between shapefiles and using original boundarys as isoclines (lines)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector

to produce a bathmertical map of a river bed I draw shapefiles showing the different depths based on satellite images taken during different tidal levels (deepest, 2nd deepest, 3rd deepest, shore etc). to produce a final map would like 2 things:
- draw isoline (lines along the boundaries of different shapefiles
- shade or make gradients from on shapefile into another that also covers little gaps between the individual shapefiles.

How can I do this using QGIS/ grass?

Answer (score 1):

The GRASS module to convert contour lines to an elevation raster is `r.surf.contour`. To run this module you need to:

- Properly define your region, including the **cell resolution**
- Convert your vector depth lines to a raster (use `v.to.rast input=... type=line output=...`)
- Now run `r.surf.contour` with the output raster from the step above as input.

Once you have an interpolated surface raster you can set it's color ramp to display as a gradient, in order to show the depths with different or darker colors.